# Need GWT SplitLayoutPanel to have max size, dragging is very jumpy

Tags: gwt

Is there a good way to set the max size for a child of a SplitLayoutPanel?  Right now I override its onResize method and call a JSNI function to set the right or width style properties of the parent div of the center panel's div, the right panel's div and the splitter panel's div, if the right/east panel is over 400px wide.

I noticed the splitter and the right panel's size don't even follow the mouse cursor and oscillate wildly between about 4/5 and 2/5 as wide as they should be based on where the mouse pointer currently is.

I have debug in eclipse and tried running it without eclipse and it's the same.  I am calling super.onResize(), as well.

Comment: Wanted to do it and failed.... Afaik, there is no standard solution avalible

Comment: Thank you...I think I'll stick with the deprecated split panel class since that doesn't jerk around when moving the separator bar.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to have a SplitLayoutPanel to occupy maximum space of the parent element. For this you can use the percentage property of width like,

```
SplitLayoutPanel slp = new SplitLayoutPanel();
slp.setWidth( "100%" );
```

And in the next step you want to add child element into the SplitLayoutPanel and it should occupy maximum area. Then set each child width to 100%

```
Widget child = // Instantiate any type of widget
child.setWidth( "100%" );
slp.add // Use proper add method and add the child to SplitLayoutPanel
```

I did not understand what did you mean by ***dragging is very jumpy***. Did you mean Splitter size is too small that you cannot find the splitter. If thas the case, you can increase the splitter size by passing it in the constructor like

```
int splitter_size_in_pixels = 5;
SplitLayoutPanel slp = new SplitLayoutPanel( splitter_size_in_pixels );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed the splitter and the right panel's size don't even follow the mouse cursor and oscillate wildly between about 4/5 and 2/5 as wide as they should be based on where the mouse pointer currently is.

I too saw jerky movement when dragging the splitter.  My south pane contained a vertical panel which contained a label and a table. The fix was to set the VerticalPanel height="100%" .  I have appended the uibinder code.

HTH
Julian

```
    <g:SplitLayoutPanel styleName="gwt-SplitLayoutPanelTtc" ui:field="splitLayoutPanel">
    <g:north size="40">
        ...
    </g:north>
    <g:west size="200">
        ...
    </g:west>
    <g:south size="500">
        <g:VerticalPanel height="100%" width="100%">
            <g:Label ui:field="tableTitle" styleName="tableTitle"></g:Label>
            <g:Grid ui:field="table" styleName="gwt-Grid"></g:Grid>
        </g:VerticalPanel>

    </g:south>
    <g:center>
        ...
    </g:center>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the jerky/jumpy movements by adding intermediate ResizeLayoutPanels.

MyComposite.ui.xml :

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" 
    xmlns:my="urn:import:my.custom.package.client">

<g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field="splitLayoutPanel">
    <g:west size="250">
    <g:ResizeLayoutPanel ui:field="leftMenuOuterPanel">
            <my:MenuWidget ui:field="menuWidget" />
        </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
    </g:west>
    <g:center>
        <g:ResizeLayoutPanel ui:field="centerOuterPanel">
            <my:AwesomeWidget ui:field="centerWidget" />
        </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
    </g:center>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

thanks to OlivierH [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898745/1034782)