# GWT SplitLayoutPanel dragging splitter is way too jumpy

Tags: gwt

Like [Need GWT SplitLayoutPanel to have max size, dragging is very jumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045924/need-gwt-splitlayoutpanel-to-have-max-size-dragging-is-very-jumpy) I am wondering why the right and the southern splitters jump (tested in IE9; both, web and hosted mode) when trying to drag the splitters in the following example:

```
public class SplitLayoutPanelTest implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final SplitLayoutPanel p = new SplitLayoutPanel(5);
        p.setSize(Window.getClientWidth()+"px", Window.getClientHeight()+"px");
        final Frame fWest = new Frame("http://bsd.org");
        fWest.setSize("400px", "200px");
        p.insertWest(fWest, 400, null);
        final Frame fEast = new Frame("http://www.linux.org");
        fEast.setSize("90px", "90px");
        p.insertEast(fEast, 100, null);
        final Frame fNorth = new Frame("http://www.w3c.org");
        fNorth.setSize("80px", "80px");
        p.insertNorth(fNorth, 100, null);
        final Frame fSouth = new Frame("http://www.sqlite.org");
        fSouth.setSize("85px", "85px");
        p.insertSouth(fSouth, 100, null);
        final Frame fCenter = new Frame("http://www.gnu.org");
        fCenter.setSize("75px", "75px");
        p.insert(fCenter, Direction.CENTER, 200, null);
        RootPanel.get().add(p);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work fine with IE8 or other browsers? Also just ensure you follow up with https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9 and

Comment: What do you mean by *splitter is way too jumpy*. Give Proper explanation or example or image. If it is regarding to what Abhijth Nagaraja is saying, set the splitter size and it will work

Comment: Does not work in FF either (tested in version 17).

Comment: By "way to jumpy" I mean the effect when trying to drag the eastern or southern splitter in the given example above in IE9 or FF 17 (not show-able by an image); the splitter does not follow mouse movement while dragging.  Btw., the splitters' size is set to 5px (new SplitLayoutPanel(5)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer  in

[Need GWT SplitLayoutPanel to have max size, dragging is very jumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045924/need-gwt-splitlayoutpanel-to-have-max-size-dragging-is-very-jumpy/13938997#13938997)

I hope this solves your issue as well, good luck

Comment: Thx, but the problem is I do not want setting child.setWidth("100%"); - I need "fixed pixeled" iframes as given in my example.

Comment: you can fix the size of a child of split panel to any pixel, that doesnt matter.. the widget you insert inside it should have width 100%

Answer (score 0):

So here is one possible solution:

```
public class SplitLayoutPanelTest implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final SplitLayoutPanel p = new SplitLayoutPanel(5);
        p.setSize(Window.getClientWidth()+"px", Window.getClientHeight()+"px");

        final Frame fWest = new Frame("http://bsd.org");
        final VerticalPanel pWest = new VerticalPanel();
        pWest.setSize("100%", "100%");
        pWest.add(fWest);
        p.insertWest(pWest, 400, null);
        fWest.setSize("400px", "200px");

        final Frame fEast = new Frame("http://www.linux.org");
        final VerticalPanel pEast = new VerticalPanel();
        pEast.setSize("100%", "100%");
        pEast.add(fEast);
        p.insertEast(pEast, 100, null);
        fEast.setSize("90px", "90px");

        final Frame fNorth = new Frame("http://www.w3c.org");
        final VerticalPanel pNorth = new VerticalPanel();
        pNorth.setSize("100%", "100%");
        pNorth.add(fNorth);
        p.insertNorth(pNorth, 100, null);
        fNorth.setSize("80px", "80px");

        final Frame fSouth = new Frame("http://www.sqlite.org");
        final VerticalPanel pSouth = new VerticalPanel();
        pSouth.setSize("100%", "100%");
        pSouth.add(fSouth);
        p.insertSouth(pSouth, 100, null);
        fSouth.setSize("85px", "85px");

        final Frame fCenter = new Frame("http://www.gnu.org");
        final VerticalPanel pCenter = new VerticalPanel();
        pCenter.setSize("100%", "100%");
        pCenter.add(fCenter);
        p.insert(pCenter, Direction.CENTER, 200, null);
        fCenter.setSize("75px", "75px");

        RootPanel.get().add(p);
    }
}
```