# GWT: SplitLayoutPanel UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, resize, uibinder

I have the same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735735/gwt-handler-to-splitlayoutpanel-drag).

Is there a way to override the onResize method and using this in a uibinder?

```
SplitLayoutPanel mainPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel() {
    @Override
    public void onResize() {
        super.onResize();
        //some other resizing stuff
    }           
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Define the class:

```
package com.foo;

public class MySplitLayoutPanel extends SplitLayoutPanel() {
  @Override
  public void onResize() {
    super.onResize();
    //some other resizing stuff
  }           
};
```

Then tie the package where the class resides, to an xml namespace of your choice (that does not clash with the others defined in the `UiBinder` template):

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:foo='urn:import:com.foo'>
```

And then reference your class through the namespace (as you would for very other widget of the commonly used `g` namespace):

```
<foo:MySplitLayoutPanel />
```

This is for the `UiBinder` part, but I don't think the answer you linked is a solution at all, since the `onResize()` will be called also (and mainly) when the browser window resizes.